# Spring MVC Controller respond on case of error

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I have the following controller method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public AbstractIngoingMessage postMessages(Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

logger.info(String.format(
              Constants.LogMessages.NEW_POST_REQUEST_FROM_IP,
              request.getRemoteAddr()));

AbstractIngoingMessage handledMessage = dispatchMessageHandling(request);   

return handledMessage;

}
```

problem is, when an error occurred on the method the response im sending back is still "CREATED" 
is there a way to respond with "ERROR" ?

Comment: We don't know your implementation of `dispatchMessageHandling(request)` or `AbstractIngoingMessage`. How are we supposed to know what you are returning?

Comment: if there is an error are you throwing an error back from the controller or are you sending an Error message back...

Comment: @Urbanleg: you should try-catch the exception and render an error message back.

Comment: Post your entire controller code. In general, you should throw an exception that goes out of the controller method and handle it in an exception handler method that has response status error.